# getting unique records of value from pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
              'id':[1134, 5321, 2444, 2444],
              'amt':[45, 55, 13, 14]})
```

I'm trying to get the count, sum, and mean, and unique ids, of the amt column.

```
df.groupby('type')['amt'].agg(['count', 'sum', np.mean])

      count  sum  mean
type                  
a         2  100  50.0
b         2   27  13.5
```

Now I'm trying to get distinct ids per grouping. if I add `id` to the columns to pull out, which yields

```
        id                 amt           
     count   sum    mean count  sum  mean
type                                     
a        2  6455  3227.5     2  100  50.0
b        2  4888  2444.0     2   27  13.5
```

Which I don't want. I want the first table, but with distinct count of *another* column. I've tried the below too with no avail.

```
df.groupby('type')['amt'].agg(['count', 'sum', np.mean, lambda x: len(np.unique(x['id']))])
```

expected output:

```
      count  sum  mean  unique_id
type                  
a         2  100  50.0  2
b         2   27  13.5  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `agg` with `nunique`.  You are not forced to pass a list to `agg`, it takes a dictionary mapping as well, which is what is needed here.

```
res = df.groupby('type').agg({'amt': ['count', 'sum', 'mean'], 'id': 'nunique'})
```

```
       amt                 id
     count  sum  mean nunique
type
a        2  100  50.0       2
b        2   27  13.5       1
```

If you want to flatten the columns (I personally think you should leave them, easier to index):

```
res.columns = res.columns.get_level_values(1)
print(res)
```

```
      count  sum  mean  nunique
type
a         2  100  50.0        2
b         2   27  13.5        1
```

Comment: brilliant. Thank you. This opened up a new understanding of grouping and pivoting. can I also use `'id': lambda x: some function`?  -as in what if I wanted to have some unique function?

Comment: Yes, you can.  I usually prefer to avoid `lambdas` as much as possible since they (usually) aren't vectorized, but you may pass a list of strings, or a list of callables, or a mix of both, or any of the above

Comment: awesome, good to know about vectorized v not. This was helpful! thanks again

Comment: I do get a deprecation warning. Is there another way to do this, just so I know?

Comment: @MattW. which version of `pandas` are you using? And what command is causing the deprecation warning?

Comment: I'm using `0.23.4`, and its.. `__main__:3: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version`